# Spring-Kafka: Rebalancing happening while using consumer pause/resume which should not as per documentation

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Spring-Kafka: While pausing/resuming consumer using pause/resume method as per documentation, rebalance should not occur when automatic assignment is used but it is not working, rebalancing happening. How to pause/resume consumer and keeping polling after a period without rebalancing?

Use Case: Consumer should pause for a period and keep polling to give heartbeat and resume after time is up but Kafka should not rebalance while consumer is paused.

```
            System.out.println("Consumer[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] Partition [" + topicPartition + "] stopped consumption.");
            consumer.pause(Collections.singleton(topicPartition));                    
            try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                    consumer.resume(Collections.singleton(topicPartition));
                    System.out.println("Consumer[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] Partition [" + topicPartition + "] resumed consumption.");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
                       e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Logs:
2019-02-19 15:19:49.173  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=customer] (Re-)joining group
2019-02-19 15:19:49.175  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=customer] (Re-)joining group
2019-02-19 15:19:49.181  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=customer] (Re-)joining group

2019-02-19 15:19:49.192  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=customer] Successfully joined group with generation 581
2019-02-19 15:19:49.192  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=customer] Successfully joined group with generation 581

2019-02-19 15:19:49.194  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=customer] Setting newly assigned partitions [spring-kafka-topic-2, spring-kafka-topic-0, spring-kafka-topic-1]
2019-02-19 15:19:49.194  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=customer] Setting newly assigned partitions [spring-kafka-topic-4, spring-kafka-topic-5, spring-kafka-topic-3]
2019-02-19 15:19:49.218  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [spring-kafka-topic-4, spring-kafka-topic-5, spring-kafka-topic-3]
2019-02-19 15:19:49.219  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [spring-kafka-topic-2, spring-kafka-topic-0, spring-kafka-topic-1]
2019-02-19 15:19:49.223  INFO 82272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-02-19 15:19:49.233  INFO 82272 --- [           main] c.g.s.S.SpringKafkaSupportApplication    : Started SpringKafkaSupportApplication in 3.43 seconds (JVM running for 3.85)
Consumer[customerTaskExecutor-1] received message[Customer(name=, phoneNumber=20)]
Consumer[customerTaskExecutor-2] received message[Customer(name=test 6, phoneNumber=6)]
Consumer[customerTaskExecutor-1] Partition [spring-kafka-topic-2] stopped consumption.
Consumer[customerTaskExecutor-1] Partition [spring-kafka-topic-1] stopped consumption.
2019-02-19 15:19:52.200  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=customer] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2019-02-19 15:19:52.200  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=customer] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2019-02-19 15:19:52.200  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=customer] Revoking previously assigned partitions [spring-kafka-topic-2, spring-kafka-topic-0, spring-kafka-topic-1]
2019-02-19 15:19:52.200  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=customer] Revoking previously assigned partitions [spring-kafka-topic-4, spring-kafka-topic-5, spring-kafka-topic-3]
2019-02-19 15:19:52.200  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [spring-kafka-topic-2, spring-kafka-topic-0, spring-kafka-topic-1]
2019-02-19 15:19:52.200  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [spring-kafka-topic-4, spring-kafka-topic-5, spring-kafka-topic-3]
2019-02-19 15:19:52.200  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=customer] (Re-)joining group
2019-02-19 15:19:52.200  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=customer] (Re-)joining group
2019-02-19 15:19:52.209  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=customer] Successfully joined group with generation 582
2019-02-19 15:19:52.209  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=customer] Successfully joined group with generation 582
2019-02-19 15:19:52.209  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=customer] Successfully joined group with generation 582
2019-02-19 15:19:52.209  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=customer] Setting newly assigned partitions [spring-kafka-topic-4, spring-kafka-topic-5]
2019-02-19 15:19:52.210  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=customer] Setting newly assigned partitions [spring-kafka-topic-0, spring-kafka-topic-1]
2019-02-19 15:19:52.210  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=customer] Setting newly assigned partitions [spring-kafka-topic-2, spring-kafka-topic-3]
2019-02-19 15:19:52.211  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-3] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [spring-kafka-topic-4, spring-kafka-topic-5]
2019-02-19 15:19:52.212  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [spring-kafka-topic-0, spring-kafka-topic-1]
2019-02-19 15:19:52.212  INFO 82272 --- [rTaskExecutor-2] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [spring-kafka-topic-2, spring-kafka-topic-3]
Consumer[customerTaskExecutor-3] received message[Customer(name=test 6, phoneNumber=6)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the Kafka documentation.

Pausing the consumer simply means that subsequent `poll()`s will return no records until you call `resume()`, but you still have to call `poll()` within `max.poll.interval.ms` in order to prevent a rebalance.

Comment: Thanks Gary for reply!!

But I am using Spring-Kafka @KafkaListner with concurrency 3 which will poll for records implicitly. Correct me if understanding is wrong.
Do I need to still call poll explicitly inside listener to avoid rebalance?

Comment: Normally the container does the poll - your listener must be able to process all the records returned by a `poll()` within the `max.poll.interval.ms` otherwise a rebalance will occur. Yes, if you `pause()` the consumer, you can safely call `poll()` within the listener but it must be on the same thread - the consumer is not thread safe. In my experience, it's better to avoid pause/resume and make sure your listener can process the records in time; perhaps reduce `max.poll.records` to help with that.

Comment: max:
        poll:
          interval: 10000
          records: 2
      heartbeat:
        interval: 1000
      session:
        timeout: 60000
There is no complex processing in listener just sysout as put in description but still rebalance is occurring.
How to avoid rebalancing? Can u pls give a short code snippet?

Comment: Perhaps the rebalance is occurring for some other reason - like starting a second instance of your application? Edit the question to show a DEBUG log. There is nothing to "show" - a rebalance should not occur if you poll within to 10 seconds (but that's a rather small interval - the default is 5 minutes).

Comment: That log is not well formatted and is hard to read. You also need to show the INFO log showing the consumer config. It does not appear the rebalance is due to a slow consumer. Share the complete app somewhere (e.g. github) and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary!!

Answer (score 3):

Just had same "group" of messages with consumers and Spring Kafka. Same results with @KafkaListener and non-annotated Spring with ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer. Parameter adjustment does not work exactly the same as straight Java.

Re-wrote with straight Java using consumer.poll() and started threads with ExecutorService - adjusted parameters per Gary Russell and everything works properly. No longer get these messages and lost heartbeat during re-balancing. Straight java examples from Clouderable and Confluent websites:

http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-consumer/index.html

https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#